# What are the best open source Nagios interfaces?

Tags: open-source, networking, monitoring, daemon, nagios

(best in your own eyes) Most features?  Coolest Features?  Slickest Design?

[Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/)?

[NagVis](http://www.nagvis.org/)?

Other?

Answer (score 3):

[Icinga](http://www.icinga.org) (a forked Nagios)

Answer (score 2):

Centreon is the best ! We use it in our company. Have a look at FAN(Fully automated Nagios) ! best best best.. and don't forget to use the lm_sensors for linux and Notify By Jabber plugin if you use Jabber and linux servers in your company and google talk ;-)

Answer (score 1):

NagVis seems to be better even if only from purely aesthetic prospective. But then for me it's one of the key elements. Maybe if you would ask more specific question (what criteria do you use to define *best*) it could be easier to answer you question.

Answer (score 1):

[Thruk](http://thruk.org) is a powerful interface for nagios, icinga and shinken. Features range from excel export to sending mass commands and plugins range from configuration editor to reporting and dasboard.